# Cannot get the selected Gridrow value on a buttonClick MVC, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im trying to get the values in a specific gridview row when clickin on it or when clicking on a button. 
The problem is that nothing happen when i click on the row, Not even when i click on the button.
The rows are unclickable. 
Any help

Here my code for the ASPx page.

```
       <%@ Page Language="C#"Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication3.Models.Order>" %>
```

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    GridView1.DataSource = ViewData["list"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {


    CheckBox x;
    foreach (DataGridItem di in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        x = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("checkBox1");
        if (x.Checked == true)
        {
            Label5.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        }
    }
 }

 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Label5.Text = string.Format("YOu selected row{0} with {1} {2}",
                               GridView1.SelectedIndex + 1,
                               GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text,
                               GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "__doPostBack('GridView1','Select$" +      e.Row.RowIndex + "');");
     } 
 }
</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tillverkning" InsertVisible="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#    Bind("TillverkningsOrder") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Datum" InsertVisible="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderDatum")     %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Antal" InsertVisible="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kundnamn" InsertVisible="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("KundNamn")           %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the rows are being rendered with the Id you are expecting? `'Select$"` seems a little presumptuous to expect it to contain that string, maybe ClientID on the controls row is what you need, been a while since I did Web Forms that is why I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

Lina,

Although i don't have the answer for your problem I have however found a data consistency issue.

When your scrolling through the checkboxes you are overtyping the Label5.Text each time. Therefore the scrolling is pointless as Label5 will only ever show the value of the last Checkbox it found to have been ticked.

May i suggest the following alternative:

```
    CheckBox x;
        foreach (DataGridItem di in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            x = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("checkBox1");
            if (x.Checked == true)
            {
                if(Label5.Text == "")
                {Label5.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;} 
                else {Label5.Text = Label5.Text + " - " +  GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;}
            }
        }
```

This will at least append the data onto the string seperating it with " - " if there are more the 1 Checkboxs selected. Feel free to change the separator as required.